# How can you change the default audio output in VLC to 5.1?

Tags: vlc-media-player, speakers, surround-sound, audio-output

Is there a setting in VLC to change default audio output to 5.1?

Comment: I guess if the source is not in 5.1 you'll have to find software that emulates 5.1 output from a stereo signal. Could be your audio driver can do that.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I felt the need to resurrect this as it’s pretty high up on search results and the solution no longer works for v2.0.2—however, I finally found a fix!

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up preferences.
2. At the bottom of the right-hand navigation select the `All` radio-button under the *Show settings* area (bottom left of the interface).
3. Now expand the *Audio* tree, select *Out Modules* and select `DirectX`.
4. Select your "Output device" and "Speaker configuration" from the drop down menus.
5. Restart VLC.

Comment: Best answer. This was working for me.

Comment: No such options under Mac OS X.

Comment: Or FreeBSD I have an "Audio output device" box to type something into - perhaps I need to give a particular device name...?

Comment: So does VLC output 5.1 to DirectX and then DirectX mixes it to stereo?

Answer (score 4):

This was a bit confusing for me as well. I have 7.1 audio on my system. VLC always defaulted to stereo audio. Then I finally figured it out. You must have your sound cards speaker configuration set to 5.1 or else VLC will not choose the 5.1 track. I thought that 7.1 set for speaker configuration on my sound card would work for anything so the system would play 5.1 or 7.1 if available. But apparently with VLC, and maybe some other programs, your system must match exactly or it will not recognize your settings. This is a feature that the VideoLan team needs to fix. With the advent of 7.1 audio VLC needs to recognize that it can play 5.1 audio on a 7.1 system.

Answer (score 3):

From `vlc --longhelp --advanced`:

```
  --force-dolby-surround {0 (Auto), 1 (On), 2 (Off)}
                             Force detection of Dolby Surround
```

There's also the respective setting in the GUI version of the settings under "Audio->Effects->Dolby Surround". Is has the options "Auto", "On" and "Off".

From what I understand, it should automatically detect whether the source media is surround sound or not.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is a setting that changes whether DS/DTS should be used in the audio channel, but not the line configurati on (stereo, left+right, 5.1....)

Comment: Okay, then this answer is probably not what you're looking for. Sorry!

Comment: @Victor "it should automatically detect whether the source media is surround sound or not." How can I tell what VLC detected?

Comment: @LimitedAtonement I believe this is available under Tools->Codec information, if you look at the audio stream and how many channels it has.

Answer (score 2):

Much better solution if you want to respect the audio mapping produced by VLC:

- Using DirectX as explained above in the solution would give an audio mapping like this :

  Stereo audio file:

  ```
  main debug: using audio filter module "scaletempo"
  main debug: conversion: 'f32l'->'f32l' 48000 Hz->48000 Hz Stereo->Stereo
  main debug: conversion pipeline complete
  main debug: conversion: 'f32l'->'f32l' 48000 Hz->48000 Hz Stereo->3F2R/LFE
  main debug: looking for audio converter module matching "any": 12 candidates
  main debug: using audio converter module "trivial_channel_mixer"
  main debug: conversion pipeline complete
  ```

  5.1 audio file:

  ```
  main debug: using audio filter module "scaletempo"
  main debug: conversion: 'a52 '->'f32l' 48000 Hz->48000 Hz 3F2R/LFE->3F2R/LFE
  main debug: looking for audio converter module matching "any": 12 candidates
  main debug: no audio converter modules matched
  main debug: looking for audio converter module matching "any": 12 candidates
  main debug: using audio converter module "a52tofloat32"
  main debug: conversion pipeline complete
  main debug: conversion: 'f32l'->'f32l' 48000 Hz->48000 Hz 3F2R/LFE->3F2R/LFE
  main debug: conversion pipeline complete
  ```
- Using WaveOut as i'll describe, respects better the audio mapping for stereo content and keep the same mapping as the first solution :

  Stereo audio file:

  ```
  main debug: using audio filter module "scaletempo"
  main debug: conversion: 'f32l'->'f32l' 48000 Hz->48000 Hz Stereo->Stereo
  main debug: conversion pipeline complete
  main debug: conversion: 'f32l'->'f32l' 48000 Hz->48000 Hz Stereo->Stereo
  main debug: conversion pipeline complete
  ```

  5.1 audio file:

  ```
  main debug: using audio filter module "scaletempo"
  main debug: conversion: 'a52 '->'f32l' 48000 Hz->48000 Hz 3F2R/LFE->3F2R/LFE
  main debug: looking for audio converter module matching "any": 12 candidates
  main debug: no audio converter modules matched
  main debug: looking for audio converter module matching "any": 12 candidates
  main debug: using audio converter module "a52tofloat32"
  main debug: conversion pipeline complete
  main debug: conversion: 'f32l'->'f32l' 48000 Hz->48000 Hz 3F2R/LFE->3F2R/LFE
  main debug: conversion pipeline complete
  ```

Now if someone feel this workaround as a proper solution, you can do it like this :

1. Press Ctrl+P to bring up preferences.
2. Go to "Audio" on left (or on top if VLC 3.0.x)
3. In output, set output module to 'WaveOut audio output', no need to change your speaker configuration as the first solution.
4. Restart VLC

Hope that will be helpful for someone...

Answer (score 1):

You need **Dolby Atmos for headphones** from Windows Store and activated **Movie preset (Detailed)**
Then,

Settings for VLC:

1. Tools > Preferences > Audio > Output Module > WaveOut audio output.
2. Device - Set your audio device.
3. Reboot VLC.

Answer (score 0):

Only if your audio format is dts/dolby digital 5.1, the 5.1 channel could activated in VLC. If the original file is of only stereo type, the 5.1 option will not get highlighted in the above said menu. You try using SURCODE DTS and Gold wave software for converting a stereo file into user defined 5.1 DTS file.

Answer (score 0):

Robin West's answer didn't work for me, but got close.

1. Tools > Preferences
2. Show Settings > [check All]
3. Audio > Output Modules > **MMDevice** (I need to double click Output Modules to see this)
4. [set Output Device]
5. reboot VLC for it to take effect

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure tow settings: **Directx** and **MMDevice**. Here is how to proceed:

**Directx**:

1. Tools > Preferences
2. Show Settings > [check All]
3. Audio > Output Modules > **Directx** > in the Speaker configuration dropdown list, select **mono**.

**MMDevice:**

3. Audio > Output Modules > **MMDevice** > in the Output back-end dropdown list, select **Directx audio output**.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example if you want to set the audio output in mono. You have to configure tow settings: **Directx** and **MMDevice**. Here is how to proceed:

**Directx**:

1. Tools > Preferences
2. Show Settings > [check All]
3. Audio > Output Modules > **Directx** > in the Speaker configuration dropdown list, select **mono**.

**MMDevice:**

3. Audio > Output Modules > **MMDevice** > in the Output back-end dropdown list, select **Directx audio output**.

Answer (score -1):

open VLC> go to preferences> select all mode in the bottom left corner> select audio> find stereo audio output mode> select Dolby Digital Surround at bottom of list. As of 2.1.5 VLC.