# How to set up VLC, MPC-HC or KMPlayer to use 5.1 speaker system?

Tags: vlc-media-player, speakers, media-player-classic, audio-output, kmplayer

I don't understand why these software do not automatically detect your speaker system and use that or assume 5.1 as default. I imagine most people have 5, 6 or 7.1.

In the very least, is there a way to configure them automatically via presets, etc? Because the settings seem obscure to me and I am not sure how to set them so that they play mkv files using the all available channels in my 5.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does other applications use the 5.1?  When you run Windows sound tests, does it play through all speakers?  Does the file include surround-sound capable audio, or is it stereo only?

Comment: Actually I don't use other applications but these are bluray files so they all have DTS audio, or AC3 in some cases. I can inspect them using mkvmerge. I haven't checked my windows setup as I just did a fresh install but it says S/PDIF.

Answer (score 1):

- For VLC see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/292911).
- For MPC-HC install [Spdifer](http://www.ac3filter.net/wiki/Spdifer):

  [image: 1]

  It should be used by all DirectShow based players automatically, although for MPC-HC some slight tweaking of the internal decoder settings may be required as the page states.
- For KMPlayer I'm not sure, but according to a post on its forum the relevant settings can be found under:

  ```
  Options / Audio Processing / Resample/Output / Speakers
  Options / Filter Control / Decoder Usage / Internal Audio Decoder / Speakers
  ```